# Can i Suppress the illigalstateexception because of reponse.getoutputstream()?

Tags: servlets

I am trying to read a PDF file and display it on browser using jsp, I understand the while rendering `response.getoutputstream()` inside jsp, I will get and illigal state exception but can i somehow suppress it or catch it inside jsp.

Comment: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/13/suppressed-exceptions-in-java-7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I can not make it a servlet due to business requrement, I need to find out a way in jsp to suppress the exception, Is there any tag which can suppress this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all whitespace between closing %> and opening <%. If that don't fix it, you'll have to use a servlet. The issue is the JSP already called getOutputStream to make the out varaiable as in like out.print()  If that happens, you're done. So you must prevent that from happening by not printing anything before calling getOutputStream and not having whitespace in the wrong spot that causes getOutputStream to be called ahead of you. The whitespace issue is kinda quirky.  Most of the time a newline character will not cause  getOutputStream to be called automatically, but when it does, its a pain. So its obviously best to just use a servlet.

Comment: Hi I can not make it a servlet due to business requrement, I need to find out a way in jsp to suppress the exception, Is there any tag which can suppress this exception?